# C#: Help Iterating through treeview items through NodeMouseClick event

Tags: c#

I created a piece of code that will display an appropriate groupbox corresponding to the treeview node being clicked like a Preferences menu form. The code does what it's supposed to do but my problem is figuring out how to make it so that another groubox will not be called into view if another item in the treeview is right clicked.

[Detailed]

Let's say there are 3 nodes in the treeview. 0) General; 1) Sounds; and 2) About; If I click node [1]Sounds, it will display the appropriate groupbox, but if I right click on treeview node [0]General, it will display it's frame and once I lift up the right click on the mouse, the focus will revert back to [1]Sounds but leave the groupbox for node 0) General. How could I failsafe this from happening?

[Code]

```
    private void tvFrames_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // How would I make sure that it won't display a different groupbox if another treeview node
        // is currently being right clicked (temporarily selected before reverting back to previous focused node item)?
        if (e.Node != null)
        {
            switch (e.Node.Index)
            {
                case 0:
                    ShowGroupBox(groupboxZero);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    ShowGroupBox(groupboxOne);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    ShowGroupBox(groupboxTwo);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer could be not to use treeView1_NodeMouseClick at all but stick with the standard treeView1_AfterSelect.

You also have a BeforeSelect which could be useful for Saving data or Canceling the move.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that these events existed. I transferred the routine from nodeclick to the afterselect event and it functioned flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Can I clarify? You just want this logic to apply on left-click, yes?

```
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Node != null)
    {
        switch(...) {
          ...
        }
    }
```

Also - rather than hard-coding index numbers, you might consider setting the `.Tag` against the nodes - avoid all the `switch` etc:

```
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Node != null)
    {
        GroupBox grp = e.Node.Tag as GroupBox;
        if(grp != null) ShowGroupBox(grp);
    }
```

Then all you need to do is set the `.Tag`s in the first place:

```
    someNode.Tag = groupboxZero;
    someOtherNode.Tag = groupboxOne;
    someThirdNode.Tag = groupboxTwo;
```

(note - this is just for cnosideration; if your code works, and you are happy - don't change it).

Comment: I have used Element.Tag a lot to but a Dictionary<Node, MyData> is less error-prone.

Comment: I appreciate the informative response but I was forced to give this answer to Henk Holterman. I wasn't aware that beforeselect and afterselect events were available and simply by transferring the routine, it worked flawlessly without having to check for mouse click or adding tags.The tag tipis appre